# Grails - Could not synchronize database state with session

Tags: angularjs, grails

When I want to make an insert I get this error. I'm using the Grails version ... can it be that I'm missing something? Thank you!

```
2019-03-08 09:08:56,705 [http-bio-8090-exec-20] ERROR events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at ar.com.mlan.api.PdCController$_save_closure2.doCall(PdCController.groovy:201)
    at ar.com.mlan.api.PdCController.save(PdCController.groovy:161)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:118)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:84)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:143)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConstraintViolationException …  so check the constraints on your domain object versus the data you are trying to save.

Comment: Hello @Codedoc ! Thanks for responding! ... You may be giving me this error because when you try to save it gives this: Batch entry 0 insert into orders_cabe. We have two servers, one for production and another for development ... In the development works perfect, the only one that gives me problems is the production

Comment: Sounds like the data in production is probably different. Did you check what you're trying to save and verify what the constraints are. Try looking for any unique constraints.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was that of all the tables that I modified (I set up a script.sql to pass the changes) there was one that had modifications "on the outside", I already corregi and it works ... thanks for lighting up!